# How to get given connection is xa or non xa for given data source?

Tags: java, datasource

Using this code I am unable to get connection is xa or non xa

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData(); 
dbmd.getDriverName();

System.out.println("DriverName - "+dbmd.getDriverName()+"DriverName class - "+dbmd.getDriverName().getClass() +"DriverName class name - "+ dbmd.getDriverName().getClass().getName());
System.out.println("DriverVersion - "+dbmd.getDriverVersion());
System.out.println("MultipleTransactions - "+dbmd.supportsMultipleTransactions());
System.out.println("Transactions - "+dbmd.supportsTransactions());
System.out.println("getClassgetName - "+dbmd.getClass().getName());
System.out.println("CLASSNAME"+(dbmd.getDriverName()).getClass().getName());
System.out.println("url - "+dbmd.getURL()+" getUserName "+dbmd.getUserName());
System.out.println("DefaultTransactionIsolation - "+dbmd.getDefaultTransactionIsolation()+"   Connection  "+dbmd.getConnection()+" Connection class  "+dbmd.getConnection().getClass()+"  Connection class name  "+dbmd.getConnection().getClass().getName());
```

Comment: no error i tried this code to find given connection is xa or non xa i want to know how can we exaclty decide that the connection is xa or non xa data source please help me

Comment: This code is not operating on a `DataSource`. The `XADataSource` interface is defined at a higher level; `DataSource`s are factories that you get connections from. Have a look through the [`javax.sql` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html), which defines the XA-related interfaces. And I'm not entirely clear on this, but I think the "XA"-ness is independent of each database per se, and supported by a middleware or coordination layer, so you wouldn't be able to tell by examining an individual connection.

Comment: ok...basically i want to find witch type of means "xa " or " non xa "  drivers are calling during establishing connection or performing transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title says "given a datasource".  Do you have access to the DataSource object?  Your code example only shows that you have access to a connection.

Assuming you have access to the datasource object you can simply do:

```
    if(myDataSource instanceof javax.sql.XADataSource)
        System.out.println("XA datasource");
    else{
        try{
            myDataSource.unwrap(javax.sql.XADataSource.class);
            System.out.println("XA datasource");
        } catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("Not an XA datasource");
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it really depends upon myDataSource object ?? because when i use weblogic server it is fine but for websphere it not working also i try for    connection con                                                                                        "con instanceof XAConnection " that is also not working in websphere

Comment: Is this something that you are curious and trying to figure out once?  Or do you need to programmatically trying to determine XA or non-XA.  If you are using websphere the configuration will tell you what type of datasource you are using.

Comment: Yes I have to do it programmatically,the result I get according  that I have to set commit or rollback in my application.Thats why it is really important for me to find XA or non-XA